# Tabbing in a loop through a winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, tabstop

I have an application where I have several forms. Its a C# windows-form based application build in .NET 4.O. I have several forms where the user enters the data. There are grids where data is displayed and whole lots of controls on the form. Believe me! its a mess of so many controls. I have to setup the `TabIndex` for each control. I have literally disabled the `TabStop` property of certain controls I don't want to be tabed into it. However, still once I go through the order I want, I TAB it, and it works but once it reaches the last box then it takes 3-4 times more tabbing to get to the first field. I tried disabling the `TabStop` property for the controls I don't want. But I think there might be certain controls that I don't see but they might be included in the Tab property. 
My question is that is there any way that I can set the `TabStop` property of all the controls on the winform to `false` and then set it to `true` for the controls I want to include only.

I also open to if there is any other way  I can implement this?

If further explanation is needed, let me know!

I have attached a picture thats the order I want and then loop back but somehow its not working. Just in addition there is also two panels in the form and I have disabled their `TabStop` property to `False`.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple explanation is that you lost a control underneath another one that overlaps it.  Or it is located beyond the edges of the Form.  A good tool to find it back is View + Other Windows + Document Outline.

If that doesn't help then diagnose it by adding a Label and a Timer.  Write the Tick event handler like this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (this.ActiveControl != null) label1.Text = this.ActiveControl.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to `View` menu and click `Tab Order`. This will activate the tab-order selection mode on the form. `TabIndex` value will be displayed as a number on each control.
2. Click on controls in order you need them to be tabbed. This will set appropriate values for `TabIndex` of controls.
3. After you finished, go to `View` menu and turn-off `Tab Order`.
4. Select controls you don't want to be tabbed and set `TabStop = false`.

Comment: This is exactly what I did but after the last txtbox its not looping back to the first txtbox?

Comment: @C_looksharp sorry, didn't get what looping you are talking about. During execution, or during tab indexes assignment?

Comment: I mean when you tab through the controls and when you reach control#  13  and then want to loop back to control#1 as shown in the picture.

Comment: @C_looksharp yes, this is a default behavior of navigation through controls

Answer (score 2):

You should try the following code:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls) 
ctrl.TabStop = false;
```

Also you can try to check the last tabindex. Then go to your form.designers.cs and find all controls with a greater tabindex and then remove them : add

```
ctrlTabStop = false;
```

I did not test any of this, so be careful : backup your *.designer.cs before.